# MongoDB Atlas: How to convert a replica set member to become Primary

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongodb-atlas-search

This document, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/force-member-to-be-primary says that one can force a replica set member to become primary by giving it a higher members[n].priority value than any other member in the set. It is for MongoDB. We use MongoDB Atlas. Does it apply to MongoDB Atlas as well?

Comment: What is preventing you from trying it and finding that out?

Comment: I am not DBA. I do not have privilege to try it out. My DBA says, "we can not have 2 primaries at the same time" with no further explanation. I am not convinced. I would like to have second opinion. Thanks.

Comment: What does having two primaries have to do with member priorities? Atlas has a free tier which you can use for free, create a cluster there and adjust its parameters the way you are proposing.

Comment: Would forcing a specific member to be primary really be helpful?  What happens if that node's hardware fails?

Comment: We are working on a blue-green system. We need to convert one of replica sets to be primary so that we can deploy new release to "green" environment that uses the converted primary DB (assume current release is running at "blue" environment). Long story short, we need to convert one of a replica sets to be primary, and be able to create another replica sets from the converted primary. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody also stumbles onto this question while googling. This is apparently not possible in Atlas. See the Unsupported commands at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/unsupported-commands/ neither replSetReconfig nor replSetGetConfig are supported.